# File Download Using Protractor to Config ChromeOptions

Tags: automation, protractor, e2e-testing

I have created an e2e test that will need to be downloaded outside of my local.

In config.js file

```
var path = require('path');
var downloadsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './downloads');

capabilities: {
'browserName': process.env.BROWSER || 'chrome',
'chromeOptions': {
    prefs: {
        'download': {
            'prompt_for_download': false,
            'default_directory': 'downloadsPath',
         },
       },
    },
 },
```

In my e2e test file

```
it('view formulary download all mapped meds test', function() {


        var mappedMedsFile = '/full_hospital_seeded_all_mapped_medications.csv';

        adminPage.viewFormulary.click();

        adminPage.downloadMappedMeds.click();

        browser.wait(function() {
            return fs.existsSync(mappedMedsFile);
        }, 30000).then(function() {
            md5File(mappedMedsFile, (err, hash) => {
                if (err) throw err
            })
            expect(md5File.sync(mappedMedsFile)).toEqual(viewFormularyResults.expectMappedMedsHash)
        });
    });
```

I was expecting this file to download correctly, but instead, I get the following error:
- Failed: Wait timed out after 30001ms

Comment: Q1 - Does it download file after clicking in the same path?
Q2 - Did you try with small file size?

Comment: Q3 - why `'downloadsPath'` is in quotes? I think it should have been `'default_directory': downloadsPath,` since otherwise js reads it as a string